# Sci-fi novel about a PI who is also a jazz musician

Tags: story-identification, books

The plot revolves around a private investigator in early 20th century Paris, who is also a jazz musician, and I believe not very successful at either. He meets a woman (presumably she comes to him with a case?), things escalate ***really quickly***, and by the end of the book he's flying off in a spaceship to destroy a Dyson sphere that has somehow appeared.

I can remember one specific scene from early on in the book: he's being persecuted by a policeman who, convinced that he has contraband hidden inside his upright bass, throws it down some stairs to smash it open.

I think it would have been a new release at around the time I read it, probably sometime between 2000 and 2010? Could well be wrong though - I got it from the library.

I've found nothing by Googling, which I'm a bit surprised by given how odd the premise is.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! It looks like you have a good question here, and a potential answer! If you need to, you can [edit] in more information. This [post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) might spark a thought on what other details you can provide.

Comment: Your question has been closed as a duplicate, but please understand that this does not mean that it is a bad question, and there's not penalty associated with the being closed. It just lets us link these questions together to improve the odds of future people finding the right book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this could well be "[Century Rain](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?153321)", a novel by Alastair Reynolds published in 2004 (just after he completed the first books of the Revelation Space series).

There are essentially two intertwined plots. The first deals with an alternate-history Paris in the 1950s, where a jazz musician named William Floyd is hired to investigate a murder. The scene you remember occurs quite early on. A policeman is convinced that the double-bass is stuffed with cigarettes or other contraband and in a struggle the bass is smashed.

The other thread of the narrative deals with Verity Auger, an archaelogist 300 years in our future. How her thread twines with Floyd's story is complicated, and involves a wormhole joining the past and future. The cover blurb describes it as:

> Something astonishing has been discovered at the far end of a
> wormhole: mid-twentieth century Earth, preserved like a fly in amber.
> Somewhere on this alternate planet is a device capable of destroying
> both worlds at either end of the wormhole. And Verity must find the
> device, and the man who plans to activate it, before it is too
> late—for the past and the future of two worlds…

Possibly the difficulty with googling it is connected to the "Dyson sphere". As far as I recall, the story does not involve this (although it does include nearly every other SF catchphrase ;)

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely it - I recognise the character names and the wormhole plot point. Not sure where I picked up the idea of the Dyson sphere from... must be from some other half-remembered book!